# How can I use a reference tag with a global set using the handle (not the ID)

Tags: globals, reference-tags

https://craftcms.com/docs/reference-tags

In my tests, only using the ID with globalsets work, e.g `{globalset:34:address}`.

I'd like to do `{globalset:misc:address}`, with `misc` being the global set handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can't.  Only element IDs will work for the reference part of the reference tag when using a global set.

Only entries get two additional formats for the reference part of the tag.

- entry-slug
- sectionHandle/entry-slug

Comment: Thought so. Feature request!