# Reference tags inside Matrix textfield

Tags: templating, matrix, globals, reference-tags

I have a `{{ siteURL }}` tag inside a matrix plain text field. But it does only render as a tag and isn't beeing converted to the actual url.

Accoring to [this post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1268/is-it-possible-to-use-twig-in-a-rich-text-field) one way is to use [reference tags](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/reference-tags).

So I write inside the matrix plain text field: `{ globalset:siteUrl }` and in the template I write:

```
{% for block in siteDropdown.matrixDropdown %}
   <li>
     <a href="{{ block.cellLink|parseRefs|raw }}">{{ block.cellLinkTitle }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

But this does nothing but print the tag itself. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the global set's element ID as the *reference* part (second segment) of the [reference tag](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/reference-tags):

```
{globalset:51:siteUrl}
```

To find the global set's ID, go to CP -> Settings -> Globals. The URL to the global set will have the ID as the last segment (e.g. `http://yoursite.craft.dev/admin/settings/globals/51`)

Also, see the this SE thread for a little more info: [How can I use a reference tag with a global set using the handle (not the ID)](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1796/how-can-i-use-a-reference-tag-with-a-global-set-using-the-handle-not-the-id)